# npm start throws sh: react-scripts: command not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

When I rename a react project, then change its name in package.json and package-lock.json, but when I run npm start command, it throws me the following error:

```
sh: react-scripts: command not found
```

I have found that usually that error is fixed by reinstalling node_modules folder. But when I run npm install it throws me the following error:

```
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! sh: node-gyp-build: command not found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/manuferreras/.npm/_logs/2022-01-26T13_27_13_876Z-debug.log
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: try to delete node_modules and `package-lock.json` too

Comment: Not working too. Throws the same npm ERR! sh: node-gyp-build: command not found error

Comment: try this command after deletion: `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Same error with cache cleaned

Answer (score -1):

Check npm version with command "npm -v"? You may need to reinstall npm

Comment: 8.1.2 , but other projects I have work perfectly. The only problem is when I rename a project

Comment: Not an anwser, should be a comment.